# Show only one text value in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to limit the text printing to one variable in a bar plot. How can I just label the pink bar `601, 215, 399, 456`?

```
ggplot(df, aes(Var1, value, label=value, fill=Var2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) + 
  geom_text(position=position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

[image]

```
structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                  4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Zero", "1-30", "31-100", "101+"
                                  ), class = "factor"), Var2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                           2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Searches", "Contact", 
                                                                                                                   "Accepts"), class = "factor"), value = c(21567, 215, 399, 456, 
                                                                                                                                                            13638, 99, 205, 171, 5806, 41, 88, 78)), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                "value"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with an `ifelse` statement in `geom_text`. First, remove `label=value` from the main ggplot2 call. Then, in `geom_text` add an `ifelse` condition on the `label` as shown below. Also, if you're dodging more than one aesthetic, you can save some typing by creating a dodging object.

```
pd = position_dodge(0.9)

ggplot(df, aes(Var1, value, fill=Var2)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=pd) + 
  geom_text(position=pd, aes(label=ifelse(Var2=="Searches", value,"")))
```

If you want the text in the middle of the bar, rather than at the top, you can do:

```
geom_text(position=pd, aes(label=ifelse(Var2=="Searches", value, ""), y=0.5*value))
```

You can actually keep the `label` statement (with the `ifelse` condition added) in the main ggplot call, but since `label` only applies to `geom_text` (or `geom_label`), I usually keep it with the geom rather than the main call.

Comment: for those looking for a plotnine solution see [here](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/466)